# Can Watt’s law be derived from the Ohm’s law without using calculus?

Tags: ohms-law, watts, formula-derivation, calculus

[image]

Unlike Ohm’s law Watt’s law is not a fundamental law of electronics, as it can be derived from other fundamental laws of electronics. In the derivation above (see the pic) I used definition of current (Q/t), voltage (E/Q), resistance (V/I) and the chain rule from calculus (dy/dx = dy/dz.dz/dx) to derive Watt’s law (P=VI).

Is there an easier, shorter and simpler derivation than this which preferably does not use calculus or any law from mechanics and which can more of less be satisfactorily explained even to a kid of 13-14 years of age?

Comment: Frame challenge: Is Ohm's law even a fundamental law, or a definition? I would generally consider it more a definition of the concept of resistance.

Comment: How did you get to step 1?

Comment: That's a lot of extra steps when you could just say $$VI = \frac{dE}{dQ}\frac{dQ}{dt} = \frac{dE}{dt} = P$$ and be done with it. It also avoids the question of why P=VI applies to circuit elements other than resistors.

Comment: Your derivation also leaves open the question of whether P=VI should apply to elements other than resistors.

Comment: I though P=I^2R was Joule's Law.

Comment: @Hearth I know it is an idealization that in reality does not exist. Like the ideal spring of physics book (k=-F/x) that does not heat up due to oscillation is  nonexistent. But to kids in school it is taught like a law. After Q=It and E=VQ Ohm's law is the first thing taught everywhere.

Comment: @BruceAbbott well I took the definition of resistance as taught in school as a first principle. Is this not what we are supposed to do in science? Start from somewhere simple and end up somewhere else exotic using mathematical logic? I have not researched the history of electricity a lot. I too am curious to know how they came up with these laws during the middle ages.

Comment: @Finbarr is it called Joule's law? Didn't know that. Was he into electricity? I thought he was more into heat engine, entropy, temperature these sort of things. I admit I am not highly informed about sciences but I guess I am interested. Please do correct me if I have said something wrong.

Comment: @ARNOBChatterjee I'm not saying it's not useful, I'm just saying it's more the definition of resistance than a law about it. Resistance doesn't have any meaning without it.

Comment: @ThePhoton you have answered my question. I started from R=V/I and it became a long story. You started from P=E/t and it was short (P = E/t = VQ/t = VI).About your second comment : if the simplest circuit is a battery and a wire and the wire converts VI joule of electric energy into heat energy, then shouldn't the battery also be converting the same amount of chemical energy to electric energy because energy can not be destroyed?Does this not imply that P=VI is true for both the resistor and the battery? I am very novice in electronics. Please do correct me if I seem to have any misconception.

Comment: Yes, the battery is converting chemical energy into electric energy. Yes P=VI applies. But V and I will have opposite signs so that P is negative. (Stick to the passive sign convention to ensure you get the right signs for V and I)